# CSS Print Media Query removing blank space

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, media-queries

Thank you for helping me out! I am trying to print a specific div using CSS Media queries. On click of print, depending on what div they click, I want to hide all other elements, except the body div they click on.

---

Everything works well, except when I go to print, the elements are where they would be originally, I'm assuming because of the 'hidden' property... the other divs are not actually gone. I cannot use display:none property because it messes up dynamically generated elements.

---

Any suggestions on how to get the selected elements to print front and center on the first page would be helpful!

---

Here is my CSS for printing

```
  <style>
        /*CSS FOR HIDING ALL ELEMENTS EXCEPT THE PRINTED ONE*/
        @media print {
            /*set all HTML elements to hidden*/
            body * {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            /*CSS classes to set chosen elements and all their children to visible*/
            .section-to-print-head, .section-to-print-body, .section-to-print-head *, .section-to-print-body * {
                visibility: visible;
                display: block;

            }
            /*POSITIONING OF HEAD*/
            .section-to-print-head {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                page-break-after: avoid;
                display: block;
            }

            /*POSITIONING OF BODY*/
            .section-to-print-body {
                position: absolute;
                left: 5;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 100;
            }
            .section-to-print-body:last-child {
              page-break-after: avoid;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

Here is the HTML with the button and onclick function

```
    <div class="row infoAreaToPrint">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <p class="h4 border-bottom mb-0">
                             Customer: <?php echo $custName ?></p>
                              <span>
                                 <button                                                          
                                  onclick="printThisTableDiv('.infoAreaToPrint')">Print Info
                                  </button>
                              </span>
```

Here is the function I call to hide all elements except what I want to print

```
    function printThisTableDiv(tableID) {
        let existingTags = document.querySelectorAll('.section-to-print-body');
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < existingTags.length; i++) {
            existingTags[i].classList.remove('section-to-print-body');
        }
        document.querySelector(tableID).classList.add("section-to-print-body");
        window.print();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out only updating the CSS query

```
   @media print {

            html, body {
                height:100%;
                margin: 0 !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            /*set all HTML elements to hidden*/
            body * {
                visibility: hidden;
                height: auto;
            }

            /*CSS classes to set chosen elements and all their children to visible*/
            .section-to-print-head, .section-to-print-body, .section-to-print-head *, .section-to-print-body * {
                visibility: visible;
                page-break-after: avoid;
            }

            /*POSITIONING OF HEAD*/
            .section-to-print-head {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            /*POSITIONING OF BODY*/
            .section-to-print-body {
                position: fixed;
                top: 50px;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 999;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .section-to-print-body ~ * {
                z-index: 0;
                display: none;
            }
        }
```